# How to pass a value from a parent window to another html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have 2 windows `home.html` and `result.html`.

In `home.html` I have a `<textarea>` *#txtinput* and a `<button>` *#btn*.

In `result.html` I have another `<textarea>` *#txtresult*.

On `home.html`, if I enter a value into *#txtinput* and click *#btn*, I want to open `result.html` and pass the *value* of *#txtinput* into *#txtresult*.

I've tried the below code from another post, which displays the value in the new window's body but won't display it in my element

```
var myWindow = window.open();
myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("txtinput").value;
```

Is it somehow possible in a simple way? I am relatively new to JavaScript, my courses are ongoing now and I am just curious to know the ways to do it. Any detailed help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I hope i need to elaborate the below code

Button on click function in the home page:

```
function sample(){
    //this will set the text box id to var id;
    var id = document.getElementById("text_box_id").id;

    //the sessionStorage.setItem(); is the predefined function in javascript
    //which will support for every browser that will store the sessions.
    sessionStorage.setItem("sent", id); 

    //this is to open a window in new tab
    window.open("result.html","_blank");
}
```

Retrieve the value in result page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //This sessionStorage.getItem(); is also a predefined function in javascript
    //will retrieve session and get the value;
    var a = sessionStorage.getItem("sent");
    alert(a);
});
```

For more information about sessionStorage

- [code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)
- [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

I have done same thing as above, am getting values in new window that's great, but that values I am getting only in documet.ready() function. So I am not able to use these values in my JSP. once I got values I need to display them in JSP.

Comment: That was a clean and nice explanation.. I got it and implemented it. good job vivek.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this code help you

This should be in home page:

```
function sample(id) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("sent", id);
    window.open("result.html","_blank");
}
```

This is another way in the same home page function:

```
function sample() {
    var id=document.getElementById("your_required_id").id;
    sessionStorage.setItem("sent", id);
    window.open("result.html","_blank");
}
```

This should be in result page:

```
function sample1() {
    var a=sessionStorage.getItem("sent");
    alert(a);
}
```

The id may be your text box id

Comment: as i already said, iam a beginner by all means. it will be a great help if you please explain important lines (like sessionstorage and how they pass value), so that i can avoid google and learn it all from here itself or atleast get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

In `result.html`, find the *Window* which opened it, using [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) and then take your data of interest from that *Window*.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { // wait for ready
    var home = window.opener, txtinput, txtresult;
    if (home) {
         txtinput = home.document.getElementById("txtinput");
         txtresult = document.getElementById('txtresult');
         txtresult.value = txtinput.value;
    }
}, false);
```

In `home.html`, listen for a click on *#btn* and open `result.html`

```
// assuming button exists at invocation time
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.open('result.html');
}, false);
```

Comment: i think this one is more simpler. i think i got the concept.

Answer (score 0):

i think that a simple assignment, using the window.opener handle from within the child window, is what you need:

```
if (window.opener) document.getElementById("#txtresult").value = window.opener.document.getElementById("#txtinput").value;
```