# How to pass variable to a new page using pop up window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a `function` which turning the `Id` of the clicked element into a variable, then a new window opens up with a new page. How can I access/use the variable on that new page?

```
var idToWrite = [];

$(function(){
    $(".szlink div").bind("click", function(){
    idToWrite.push($(this).attr("id")); 
    window.open("itemEncJS.html");
    //do something
});
```

Comment: hi, firs use search and then put a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219977/how-to-pass-a-value-from-a-parent-window-to-another-html-page-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a value from a parent window to another html page using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219977/how-to-pass-a-value-from-a-parent-window-to-another-html-page-using-javascript)

Comment: @Christophvh I was tempted to flag it for being a duplicate, but I think it differs enough just by using jQuery.

Comment: The link is not including jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use local storage:
on current page:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
storage.setItem('id', id);
```

on the new page:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
var id = storage.getItem('id');
```

Comment: Security is not important where i need this for :) A7S's answer is the winner for me, however, thanks both of you for the effort, and help!

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe and it is not meant to use plain html to process requests from urls.

However if you really want to do it, you can open the popup with the url with the values like this:

```
window.open("itemEncJS.html?name1=value1&name2=value2");
```

Then in the second page you will have to use regex to pick the value from url, something like this:

```
url = window.location.href;
nameValuePairs = url.match(/[\w]*=[\w]*/ig)
values = {}
nameValuePairs.forEach(function(pair){
  nv = pair.split("=");
  values[nv[0]] = nv[1];
})
```

Now you can use **values** to get your required values
e.g

```
val1 = values[name1]
val2 = values[name2]
```